# Python multiprocessing not executing in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is not my actual program but it illustrates my issue. This is the code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
import random
O = open("test.txt","w")
for i in range(10000000):
    O.write("%s\n" % (random.randint(0,9)))
O.close()

def worker(number):
    subprocess.call("awk \'$1==%s\' test.txt> test.%s.txt" % (number,number),shell=True)
    return number

pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
results = [pool.apply(worker, args=(x,)) for x in range(10)]
print(results)
```

This code is working fine however I noticed that the awk commannds are executing sequentially instead of 3 at a time. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`multiprocessing.Pool.apply`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply)...

> blocks until the result is ready. Given this blocks, [`apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) is better suited for performing work in parallel.

If your core work really involves launching subprocesses rather than doing work natively in Python, you also might consider just outright launching a bunch of [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) objects in a single Python process, then [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) and [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) on each of them.  This saves a layer of process, but it can be much trickier to collect outputs of the subprocesses if they're writing things to their own stdout.

Comment: If the inputs and outputs can be treated as sequence, then `Pool.map` or Pool.imap_unordered` are probably a better choice and `apply_async`. Also, using `multiprocessing.dummy` might be better than rolling your own subprocess launcher.